# SImple form input as float add float class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3

I can't understand what is the purpose of mentioning a float class to out put HTML code.. The problem am facing due to this rail feature is that next element come next to it instead of coming right after it. Is there any easy way to fix this instead of using JQuery or over write inpput to display it as integer/string.. To remove that class float.. Kindly reply ASAP.. 
          `:as=>:float` need to change to `:as=>:string`
Thanks..

```
 <%= f.association :resource, :required=>:true, %>
      <%= f.input :join_date,:as=>:string,  :required=>:true, :input_html=>{:class=>'datepicker'} %>
      <%= f.association :resource_role, :required=>:true, :label=>"Role" %>
      <%= f.association :resource_billing_type, :required=>:true, :label=>"Billing Type"  %>
      <%= f.input :billing_rate, :as=>:float, :required=>:true, %>
```

[image: Image of Question]

Comment: This is a plain html/css problem. Could you show some html and css. This is easy to solve, but it depends on your exact code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with others that seeing the html output and css code would make answering this question easier. My guess is that you have some CSS saying "float:left;" and that following that, and before the save and cancel button you need to simply add a div with "clear:both;" as the CSS. Then the submit and cancel buttons will go below.

It's also possible that you could remove the float and just use relative positioning for the billing rate.

Answer (score 1):

The `:as=>:float` has nothing to do with css, it is used to specify that the input type will be a floating point number (this is so that simple form can perform some validations on the user input).

What you need to look is the default tag simple form is putting around your css elements which is probably a div by default. Thus, the problem could be fixed with CSS or by changing it to a paragraph tag with:

`SimpleForm.wrapper_tag = :p`

If you need a quick hack to fix it I would imagine you can just throw in a html line break tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
input[type="text"] {
  clear: right;
}
```

Making sure nothing floats on the right side of the input elements with type text.

Answer (score 0):

Using floats in forms is pretty common.

Normally your button have a left-margin equalling the width of the labels.

I am assuming your label + input fields are either inside `li` or `div` blocks.

I assume your submit button should also be inside such a `li` or `div` and that is missing.